# Can I prompt user for Field Mappings in SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to build a tool to facilitate some redundant importing of data into a SQL Server database. The flat text files we get have are mostly static, but there is often about a 5-10% variance in field names and sometimes some extra fields added (in which we will add columns to the table in the database before importing).

I'd like to build a front end interface for a SSIS package to make the field mapping the only real work for the user as I don't think we can program it. Is there anything out there that would allow this? Should I consider something other than SSIS? Appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: If you want it to work interactively with the user, then yes you will have to use asp or something like that.   SSIS isn't interactive.

Comment: You *can* build your SSIS packages through the SSIS object model. Workflow would be: Collect mappings -> Build SSIS package(s) -> Run but that's going to be a bit painful unless you really like coding. What you can't do is modify the mappings once the package is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS packages are generally headless because they typically will run as a scheduled job somewhere on a database server. That said, there are definitely ways to do this.

One option that I have used is [SQL Management Objects (SMO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to connect to the SQL Server Agent where the job is hosted. A client can interactively run such a job and even update the user on execution status. The same client could ask the user for input prior to kicking off the job, and you could store such input in a place where the package can access it.